# is "HelloWorld" a valid json response

Tags: json, wcf, rest

This could be the most basic json question ever. I'm creating a WCF REST service and have a HelloWorld test function that just returns a string. I'm testing the service in fiddler and the reponse body I'm getting back is:

```
"HelloWorld"
```

I also created a function that would just return a number (double) and the response body is:

```
1.0
```

Are those valid json responses? Are simple return types just returned in plain text like that (no markup with the brackets)?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18419428/what-is-the-minimum-valid-json, where the question was phrased more broadly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Valid JSON responses start with either a `{` for an object or `[` for a list of objects.

Native types are not valid JSON if not encapsulated. Try [JSONlint](http://jsonlint.com/) to check validity.

Answer (score 5):

[RFC 4672](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4627), says no.  Which doesn't mean it can't work, but it isn't strictly standards compliant.  (Of course, neither are all the JSON readers...)

To quote from Section 2, "JSON Grammar":

> A JSON text is a sequence of tokens.  The set of tokens includes six
> structural characters, strings, numbers, and three literal names.
>
> A JSON text is a serialized object or array.
>
> JSON-text = object / array

Only objects / maps, and arrays, at the top level.

Answer (score 3):

According to the [official website](http://json.org), you need to use a syntax like this:

[image: JSON Syntax]

You need to declare what you want beetween `{}`, like this:

```
{
    "test": "HelloWorld"
}
```

Comment: Not quite right, since an array is valid JSON too.  Unfortunately json.org isn't explicit on what are valid root nodes in the grammar.

Answer (score 0):

No. The following is, for example:

```
{
    "Foo": "HelloWorld"
}
```

You can try [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/) to see what validates and what does not.