# How to convert the following odd string into json in python?

Tags: python, json, types

How to convert this string into json in python?

```
>>> data = '[for: css=a[title="See LLCAutoSept files"]]'
>>> json.dumps(data)
'"[for: css=a[title=\\"See LLCAutoSept files\\"]]"'
```

I've tried using json.dumps(), however the output json is could not be validated on jsonlint.com

Comment: the problem is that this isn't json

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are looking at the Python string representation. It's valid Python code, **containing** valid JSON.

Print the value:

```
>>> imp
>>> data = '[for: css=a[title="See LLCAutoSept files"]]'
>>> print json.dumps(data)
"[for: css=a[title=\"See LLCAutoSept files\"]]"
```

JSONlint is using the *older*, [stricter RFC 4627](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4627) that requires the top level to be an array or object, so it won't validate a JSON string.

However, Python's `json.dumps()` produces valid [RFC 7159](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7158) output.

If your application requires JSONlint compliance, then by all means add a list or dictionary:

```
>>> print json.dumps([data])
["[for: css=a[title=\"See LLCAutoSept files\"]]"]
>>> print json.dumps({'data': data})
{"data": "[for: css=a[title=\"See LLCAutoSept files\"]]"}
```

JSONlint.com validates either of these as valid.

There was, for a time, quite some confusion over this, with RFC 4627, ECMA-262 and ECMA-404 and actual implementations disagreeing over what was allowed; at least RFC 7159 agrees with ECMA-404 now on this. Also see [What is the minimum valid JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18419428/what-is-the-minimum-valid-json)

Comment: i think the problem is that jsonlint.com won't accept string only json

Comment: @Bastian: I am addressing that, yes.

Comment: Thanks for all the inputs. You guys are correct. If i print the json.dumsp(data), i only get 1 slash. But if I don't print it, why does the interpreter output the string with double slashes? see my original example. Thanks!

Comment: @user3388884: because you are given a *Python string representation*, for ease of debugging. You can paste that representation back into the interpreter and it'll *recreate the original string value*.

Comment: @user3388884: it is the equivalent of `print repr(json.dumps(data))`.

Answer (score 1):

This is not valid json because it does not have a key for the array and opening and closing curly or square brackets, that is why you cannot validate it on jsonlint.com

Comment: JSON does not require the top level to be an object.

Comment: Hence why I said `opening and closing curly or square brackets` meaning it can be an object OR array @MartijnPieters so if you could please change your vote that'd be great. Thanks

Comment: That's still only true for the older (superseded) [RFC 4627 standard](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4627); [RFC 7158](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7158) allows for any JSON type as the top level.

Comment: @MartijnPieters that's what heinst said. He doesn't contradict you, you don't get his message. It's not about the top level. It simply isn't json

Comment: @IvoBeckers: It's a plain string, dumped to JSON. The string contents are not valid JSON, but the output of `json.dumps()` *is*. But JSONlint doesn't validate that either because *it* is following an older outdated RFC.

Comment: @Bastian: hehehe, thanks. Still, March 2014, that's new enough.

Comment: O now, I see. There's been a slight misunderstanding here. My point (and also heinst's I think) was that the original string is not valid json, not the dumped one

Comment: @Bastian: I feel cheated now. 7158 and 7159 differ only in the date of publication and the RFC number. Oh, and 7158 has been marked as superseded by 7159... *There are no other differences*.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me

```
data = {'string':'[for: css=a[title="See LLCAutoSept files"]]'}
print(json.dumps(data))
```