# Unexpected end of JSON input in post request

Tags: reactjs, laravel

hope you can clarify this issue:

I am trying to create a simple react form updating the data in the database, my React code is as it follows:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';


export default function Form() {
    const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
    const [name, setName] = useState('');
    const [text, setText] = useState('');

    const handleEmail=(e)=>{
        
        setEmail(e.target.value)
    }
    const handleName=(e)=>{
        
        setName(e.target.value)
    }
    const handleText=(e)=>{
        
        setText(e.target.value)
    }
    const handleSubmit=(e)=>{

        e.preventDefault();
        if(name&&email&&text!==''){
             sendData()
        }else{
            console.log('fill the stuf')
        }
    
    }
    const sendData=()=>{

        fetch('http://www.contact.test/api/contact',{
            method:'post',
            body:JSON.stringify(
                {email,name,text}
            ),
            headers:{
                'Accept':'application/json',
                'Content-Type':'application/json',
            }
        }).then(function(response){
            response.json().then(function(resp){
                console.log(resp)
            })
        })
        setText('')
        setEmail('')
        setName('')

    }
    
    return (
        <>
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                <label>Email</label>
                <input onChange={handleEmail} type="email" value={email} placeholder="Enter email"/>
                <label>Name</label>
                <input onChange={handleName} type="text" value={name} placeholder="Enter Name"/>
                <label>Text</label>
                <textarea onChange={handleText} value={text} placeholder="Enter Text"/>
                <button type="submit">Send</button>
            </form>
        </>
    )
}
```

however I am getting an error when fetching the data,

```
Form.jsx:43 Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
    at Form.jsx:43
```

the most important part for the fetch is this one, line 43 comented for you to identify:

```
    const sendData=()=>{

        fetch('http://www.contact.test/api/contact',{
            method:'post',
            body:JSON.stringify(
                {email,name,text}
            ),
            headers:{
                'Accept':'application/json',
                'Content-Type':'application/json',
            }
        }).then(function(response){
            response.json().then(function(resp){>**//this is line 43**
                console.log(resp)
            })
        })
        setText('')
        setEmail('')
        setName('')

    }
```

my bakcend is with Laravel 7:

```
class ContactController extends Controller
{
    function contact(Request $request)
    {
        $contact = new Contact;
        $contact->name=$request->input('name');
        $contact->email=$request->input('email');
        $contact->text=$request->input('text');
        $contact->save();

        return $contact;
    }
}
```

the route is

```
Route::post('/contact', 'ContactController@contact');
```

I am a bit confused since I managed to send some request into the DB but suddently it started to complain about CORS, I installed the chrome extension and now this happens.

Hope you have a suggestion.

Thanks

**edit**
the problem apppeared when trying to set up an automatic email after submiting the form, in the developer tools/network/headers when I fill the .env file in laravel with the information of the email, 2 new headers appear:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is `response` an empty string? If yes, check https://stackoverflow.com/q/30621802/2873538

Comment: thanks for your reply, I was just updating my question since the problem looks like from the laravel,

Comment: I guess the json format is wrong in the post request

Comment: is related with the laravel for sure, the problem appears when trying to send the email

Comment: Can we see what the contact call returns?

Comment: @mrhn it says "this request has not data available"