# Use localStorage.getItem() with typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, local-storage

I have the following line of code:

```js
const allGarments = teeMeasuresAverages || JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("teeMeasuresAverages")) || teeMeasuresAveragesLocal;
```

Typescript throws this warning:

```
Argument of type 'string | null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
  Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'string'.
```

So I tried including the non-null assertion operator (!):

```js
const allGarments = teeMeasuresAverages || JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("teeMeasuresAverages")) || teeMeasuresAveragesLocal;
```

Which then gives me a different warning:

```
Forbidden non-null assertion.
```

I'm new to typescript. What is it looking for here?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Type of `JSON.parse` dependency must be a `string` .

But the `local storage` return type is `string|null` so it can be both `string` and `null` and when you declare the data, its value is null until you render the component (or call the function) and then call the `getItem` function, it gets the value, and then it's a `string`.

You can use `||` operator and add a string to it so that it is not null anymore.

```
JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("teeMeasuresAverages") || '""')
```

Also you can add `// @ts-ignore` to prevent TypeScript to check the types in the next line, but it is not recommended

```
// @ts-ignore
JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("teeMeasuresAverages"))//just the usual way
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm still getting ```Argument of type 'string | null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
  Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'string'.```

Comment: try it also for `json.parse` `JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("teeMeasuresAverages")||"")`

Comment: in order to use `||` you should put it after expression `localStorage.getItem("teeMeasuresAverages") || ""`

Comment: I'm afraid this is wrong. `JSON.parse("")` returns `Unexpected end of JSON input`. Thus your code breaks the whole app if the item does not exist (yet).

Comment: To get this accepted answer working, you need to ```|| '""'``` otherwise you still get an ```Unexpected end of JSON input``` back, due to the fact that an empty string is not valid JSON, but a string that is empty is (huh?). That's right, check out a more elaborate answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30621802/why-does-json-parse-fail-with-the-empty-string#answer-30621997)

Answer (score 12):

`JSON.parse` expects `string` as a first argument

```js
JSON.parse(text: string, reviver?: ((this: any, key: string, value: any) => any) | undefined): any
```

When `localStorage` returns `string | null`.

```js
const value = localStorage.getItem("teeMeasuresAverages") // string | null
```

If you want to make TS happy just check if `value` is a stirng

```js
const value = localStorage.getItem("teeMeasuresAverages")

if (typeof value === 'string') {
    const parse = JSON.parse(value) // ok

}
```

Comment: Thanks! This seems really verbose for a simple localStorage request, but it's the best solution I've encountered all the same.

Comment: you can check if value is a string in any way you want. Using `||` is completely legal. I just wanted to explain why TS complains

Comment: Unfortunately this is not enough since in some cases it returns string 'undefined' when it doesn't find the item which is strange, but check out my answer.

Answer (score 3):

So with the given solutions there is an error you can't parse an empty string.
It will give you an error of `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input` for `JSON.parse("")`. More details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30621802/why-does-json-parse-fail-with-the-empty-string).

So my solution would be use `||` part to give a default value of what you will want to happen if you can't find the variable you were looking for in the local storage. For e.g.

```
JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("isItTrueOrFalse") || "false")
```

Answer (score 1):

In general:

```
  const item = localStorage.getItem(itemName)
  const result = item ? JSON.parse(item) : undefined
```

Function for getting item from localStorage in Next.js can look like this:

```
const ISSERVER = typeof window === 'undefined'
export const getItemFromLocalStorage = (itemName: string) => {
  if (ISSERVER) return
  const item = localStorage.getItem(itemName)
  return item ? JSON.parse(item) : undefined
}
```

and we can move the `ISSERVER` to `constants/window.ts`

Answer (score -3):

I found out that this seems to help me while using typescript:

```
JSON.parse(`${localStorage.getItem('localStorage-value')}`);
```