# Argument of type 'string | null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am very beginner in typescript. I am trying to get my local storage variable `auth` value. I know variable in local storage are stored as a string. So I am converting it into Boolean using `JSON.parse` But I am getting error saying [Argument of type 'string | null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.   Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'string'].

Getting error at line: 2 where I am declaring `auth` Variable

```
let leftmenu;
    const auth:boolean = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('auth'));
    if (auth === true) {
        leftmenu = (
            <React.Fragment>
                <Navbar.Text>
                    Signed in as: <a href="#login">Mark Otto</a>
                </Navbar.Text>
                <Button variant="outline-success">Logout</Button>
            </React.Fragment>);
    } else {
        leftmenu = (
            <React.Fragment>
                <Button variant="outline-success">Login</Button>
                <Button variant="outline-success">Sign Up</Button>
            </React.Fragment>
        )
    }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use localStorage.getItem() with typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67700374/use-localstorage-getitem-with-typescript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because it's possible that `localStorage.getItem('auth')` will return `null`, while `JSON.parse` requires a string.

You will need to do a null check before parsing the variable.

```
cosnt authRaw: string = localStorage.getItem('auth');
if(authRaw !== null){
    const auth: boolean = JSON.parse(authRaw);
}
```

A simpler approach is to use `??` to add a fallback value as an alternative to `localStorage.getItem('auth')`

```
const auth:boolean = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('auth') ?? "false");
```

Comment: It possible but not always return null. If there is a value in it then there will be no null value

Comment: Yes, that's why it has the type `string | null`, which denotes the fact that it can be either of them.

Comment: TypeScript enforces you to guarantee that `JSON.parse` gets a `string`, so that everything that happens inside `JSON.parse` will work as expected.

Comment: else condition is also defined if I get null from localstorage then the else part will run. So, why it is throwing an error?

Please explain in simple way

Comment: What I expect from my condition is if the ```auth``` variable is true then run if part. If anything available in ```auth``` rather than ```true``` then run else part

Comment: I see. The error occurs at this line in your code, `const auth:boolean = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('auth'));`. This error is raised by TypeScript complaining that `JSON.parse` requires a `string`. There is really nothing wrong with your if-else statement.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
const auth: string | null = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('auth'));
if (auth!== null) {
    if(auth=="true") {
    leftmenu = (
        <React.Fragment>
            <Navbar.Text>
                Signed in as: <a href="#login">Mark Otto</a>
            </Navbar.Text>
            <Button variant="outline-success">Logout</Button>
        </React.Fragment>);
} else {
    leftmenu = (
        <React.Fragment>
            <Button variant="outline-success">Login</Button>
            <Button variant="outline-success">Sign Up</Button>
        </React.Fragment>
    )
}
}
```

Comment: What I expect from my condition is if the ```auth``` variable is true then run if part. If anything else in ```auth``` rather than ```true``` then run else part. So, what's wrong in my condition ?

Comment: Your condition is okay, but you need to make sure that the localStorage item 'auth' must not be null. In your case it is getting value as null. that is why I added string | null because, let say, if the Parse get null, atleast you have a way to handle it