# Argument of type 'string | null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'. Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'string'. Angular 12

Tags: angular, typescript, angular12, typescript4.0

JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('owner')) 
==>
Argument of type 'string | null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'string'.

And the return null;
==>
Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'string'.

```
public get owner(): Owner{
if(this._owner != null){
  return this._owner;
} else if (this._owner == null && sessionStorage.getItem('owner') != null){
  this._owner = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('owner')) as Owner; // <== HERE
  return this._owner;
}
return new Owner();
```

}

```
public get token(): string{
if (this._token != null) {
  return this._token;
} else if (this._token == null && sessionStorage.getItem('token') != null) {
  this._token = sessionStorage.getItem('token') as string;
  return this._token;
}
return null;   // <== HERE: Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'string'.
```

}

Comment: `null` really is not assignable to type `string`. If you want your function to be able to return a string or null, set its return type to `string | null`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Argument of type 'string | null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68357873/argument-of-type-string-null-is-not-assignable-to-parameter-of-type-string)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You define `token()` as returning only a `string`, yet you're trying to return `null`. You can change the definition to return `string | null`:

```js
public get token(): string | null {
    if (this._token != null) {
        return this._token;
    } else if (this._token == null && sessionStorage.getItem('token') != null) {
        this._token = sessionStorage.getItem('token') as string;
        return this._token;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Of course the code using this getter needs to account for that.