# Argument of type 'string | null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string | undefined'

Tags: angular, typescript

The subject exists [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68503665/argument-of-type-string-null-is-not-assignable-to-parameter-of-type-string) also, but I'm still stuck.

I have an error in the `isAuth()` method:

```
Error: src/app/services/auth.service.ts:22:38 - error TS2345: Argument of type 'string 
| null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string | undefined'.

Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'string | undefined'.

22     if(this.jwtHelper.isTokenExpired(token) || !localStorage.getItem('token')){
```

I don't understand what I have to change?

```
isAuth():boolean{
    const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
    if(this.jwtHelper.isTokenExpired(token) || !localStorage.getItem('token')){
      return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cYrdD.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the value of `token` is nullable because if there is no value for the key 'token' in your local storage, then `localStorage` returns null.
so what you can do is:
first check if there is a value for token or not.

```
isAuth():boolean{
    const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
    if((token && this.jwtHelper.isTokenExpired(token)) || !localStorage.getItem('token')){
      return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

but the better approach is this:

```
isAuth():boolean{
    const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
    return token && !this.jwtHelper.isTokenExpired(token);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe `isTokenExpired()` is expecting either a string or `undefined`, but `getItem()` returns a string or `null`.

Do something like:

```
return token == null ? false : this.jwtHelper.isTokenExpired(token)
```