# @Consumes("application/json") with list of doubles not working

Tags: java, json, jax-rs, jersey-2.0, moxy

I have started learning JAX-RS using jersey 2.x.
I am trying to make a PUT request with curl:

```
curl -v -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X PUT -d "[10.0,10.0]" localhost:8080/location
```

But I am getting 415 Unsupported Media Type. 
For my JSON provider I am using Moxy

```
@PUT
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response setLocation(final List<Double> coordinates) {

}
```

Changing

```
List<Double>
```

to

```
List<String>
```

doesnot give the 415 error. I think there must be some issue with the parser!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18419428/what-is-the-minimum-valid-json [10.0,10.0] is a valid JSON

Comment: What does it do with `List<?>` (and if no 415 what types are in the list?)

Comment: Possibly related: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=459227

Comment: It gives 415 with List<?>

Comment: But it does work with List<String>. By the way, List<Double> works if it is a field in a Json Object, like {"location":[10.0,10.0]}