# Reading a string with Java REST Client (Apache CXF or Jersey)

Tags: java, json, rest, jax-rs, jersey-2.0

I don't understand why when I receive a json encoded string this is not decoded automatically. 
I tried this code using Apache CFX 3.1.4 or Jersey 2.22.1:

```
Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient().register(JSONProvider.class);

WebTarget target = client.target("http://example.org/rest/service1");
target = target.queryParam("method", "method1");

Entity<EndpointRequest> entity = Entity.entity(new EndpointRequest("0000"),
                       MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
Response response = target.request()
                    .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                    .post(entity);

System.out.println( response.getStatus() );

if (response.getStatus() == 200) {
// The problem comes here
    String basePath = response.readEntity(String.class);
    System.out.println( basePath );
}
```

The request is successfully executed but `basePath` contains `"\/opt\/local\/application\/rest\/"`  (backslash and double quotes included)

`basePath` should instead contain this:  `/opt/local/application/rest/`

It seems to me, the json deserialization hasn't be triggered when it should.

Comment: Might be a problem with JSON serializer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the server response. A server should not return only a quoted string, even if correctly encoded, because [a string is not a valid JSON object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18419428/what-is-the-minimum-valid-json).

Answer (score 0):

You created a Client and a WebTarget but never actually used them. You end up using Entity and Response instead. I'm not sure what library you're using, but I would think you would need to actually use Ciient and WebTarget to invoke JSONProvider.

Comment: now I'm using cxf 3.1.4. I have fixed the code, where you say I don't use the webtarget