# Is empty body correct if Content-Type is application/json?

Tags: json, http, request, response

I return Status code 401 if token is wrong for the endpoint '/tokens/verify' and don't need to send any body content to user.

Is it correct to send an empty body for `application/json` content type?

Answer (score 14):

No, it's not. If you declare the payload to be JSON, you need to send JSON. The status code is irrelevant with respect to this.

Empty body is not valid JSON. [Minimum valid JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18419428/113116) would be `{}`, `[]`, `""` (empty string enclosed in quotes), `null`, etc., but empty body is not valid JSON.

Comment: Is this your personal opinion, or based on the HTTP standard or something related?

Comment: It's based on the definition of the HTTP Content-Type header field in https://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/rfc7231.html#header.content-type - note that the definition of the header field does not even mentions the status code.

Comment: sometimes one needs to think a bit more at what is achieved than simply follow certain so perceived standards to the letter. There is no value from returning an empty JSON object, that does not provide any value. everything one needs to know is in the HTTP code.

Comment: Explain "perceived standard".

Comment: It's also "just" a WebDAV standard, so keep that in mind.

Comment: @VinceVarga - what exactly are you talking about? RFC 7231?

Comment: @AndreiDragotoniu if you don't want to return JSON, just don't set the content type.

Comment: @VinceVarga no, it's not "just a WebDAV standard". It's a regular RFC: https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7231. Just because one of the authors worked on WebDAV doesn't make everything he works on a WebDAV standard.

Comment: Thanks for correcting the record (It's been 4 years ago, so I have no idea what I was saying)

Comment: @AndreiDragotoniu Please just follow the standards. It's so freaking tiring having to deal with special cases all the time. I thought we were past that since ES6.