# Is it possible to create a no content class with Newtonsoft.Json?

Tags: .net, json.net

I'm currently creating a library that will handle ApiResponses in .NET

What it looks like at the moment:

```
ApiResponse{}
SuccessfulResponse: ApiResponse{}
FailedResponse: ApiResponse{}
```

I'm trying to create an `EmptySuccessfulResponse` for 204 responses, but the issue is that Newtonsoft.Json will always add the curly braces.

My main question is: Is there an annotation like `[JsonIgnore]` but for an entire class? The reason for that is to avoid a `return null;` in my Controller.

Comment: These responses are built-in already

Comment: A zero-length string is not well-formed JSON, as a zero-length string value is serialized to JSON as `""`.  Thus the minimum valid JSON is `[]`, `{}`, `""`, `0` or `null`.  See [What is the minimum valid JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18419428/3744182).

Comment: Thus, for instance, Json.NET serializes as `null` **root** value as `null` even when `NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore`, see https://dotnetfiddle.net/y0Bc4E