# How to safely convert object to Record

Tags: typescript

How do I safely convert a Typescript `object` to `Record<PropertyKey, unknown>`? For example, when reading JSON you get an `any` object which should really be `unknown` (I assume it isn't for backwards compatibility):

```js
const ob = JSON.parse("{}") as unknown;
```

I can convert the `unknown` to an `object` using a type assertion:

```js
if (typeof ob !== "object" || ob === null) {
  throw new Error("Not an object");
}
// Typescript now infers the type of ob as `object`
```

But what check do I now do to convince Typescript that it is safe to treat it as `Record<PropertyKey, unknown>`? Is it possible that there are `object`s that aren't `Record`s?

I'm sure it has to be said, but I am *not* looking for `ob as Record<PropertyKey, unknown>`.

Comment: Check https://github.com/gcanti/io-ts (https://gcanti.github.io/io-ts/)

Comment: The value could be a number. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18419428/what-is-the-minimum-valid-json/18419503

Comment: No because then `typeof ob` would return `"number"`.

Comment: I'd love a real answer to this rather than people focusing too much on the specific example.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Jack Wilson, this works, though extending the `Object` interface does seem a little icky.

```js
interface Object {
    [index: string]: unknown; // You can't do `[index: PropertyKey]` or `[P in PropertyKey]` for some reason.
    [index: number]: unknown;
}

const ob = JSON.parse("{}") as unknown;

if (!(ob instanceof Object)) {
  throw new Error("Not an object");
}

const a = ob["foo"]; // a is unknown.
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to io-ts mentioned in comments, check out zod for your use case: https://github.com/vriad/zod/

```
import * as z from 'zod';

// I believe this kind of circular reference requires ts 3.7+
type JsonValue =
  | { [index: string]: JsonValue }
  | JsonValue[]
  | boolean
  | null
  | number
  | string;

type JsonObject = { [index: string]: JsonValue } | JsonValue[];

const valueSchema: z.ZodSchema<JsonValue> = z.lazy(() => {
  return z.union([
    z.record(valueSchema),
    z.array(valueSchema),
    z.boolean(),
    z.null(),
    z.number(),
    z.string(),
  ]);
});

const objectSchema: z.ZodSchema<JsonObject> = z.lazy(() => {
  return z.union([z.record(valueSchema), z.array(valueSchema)]);
});

// results in a correctly typed object, or else throws an error
objectSchema.parse(JSON.parse('whatever unknown string'));
```

Comment: Useful information, though I'm still interested in an answer to the original question.

Comment: An instance of Date is an object but is not a Record, for example.  I can't think of anything short of a type guard for assuring tsc that the value output by JSON.parse will be a record.

Comment: A `Date` object is a `Record`. What makes you think it isn't?

Comment: Tried it and tsc wouldn't allow it: [eval].ts:1:7 - error TS2322: Type 'Date' is not assignable to type 'Record<string | number | symbol, unknown>'.

Comment: You have to do `let a = new Date() as unknown as Record<PropertyKey, unknown>;`. The very point of this question is how do I convince Typescript that I don't need the casts?

Comment: Isn't the `as` type assertion simply disabling the check altogether?  e,g, `let x = new Date() as unknown as string[];` and `let b: Boolean = 'hello' as unknown as boolean;` works, though they don't actually make sense.  In the case of assigning a date to a Record, the specific error is `Index signature is missing in type 'Date'.`.  I suppose it's not enough to have string/unknown pairs; date's type must define an index signature as well.  So, I think you cannot convince tsc to accept this except by using the check-disabling assertions you are trying to avoid.

Comment: Maybe I didn't explain well enough: `Date` *does* satisfy the `Record<PropertyKey, unknown>` contract. In other words if I force (via `as`) Typescript to convert a `Date` to `Record`, then nothing I can do with the resulting record will result in a type error. Because that is the case, I *shouldn't need the `as` cast*. Does that make sense?

Comment: Now I see what you mean.  In that case, you can eliminate the type error by adding your own index signature to its interface: `interface Date { [index: PropertyKey]: unknown; }`.  Interfaces merge, so you won't mangle the existing one.

Comment: Ah that does actually work! I couldn't change `object` because it is a keyword, but I was able to extend `Object`.