# Error reading JObject from JsonReader. Path '', line 0, position 0

Tags: c#, asp.net, json

I am running my solution locally, trying to read a .json file location stored in the Web.config file, that resides to a location on a test server.

Web.config:

```
<add key="TokenFilePath" value="\\test\inetpub\wwwroot\meetings\token.json"/>
```

This is the line where I get the error:

```
 var token = JObject.Parse(System.IO.File.ReadAllText(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TokenFilePath"]));
```

Exception:

> Exception Details: Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: Error reading JObject from JsonReader. Path '', line 0, position 0.

If I change the location of the token.json file to a location in the network like below, then I am able to read the file.

```
\\data\applications\meetings\credentials\token.json
```

Is this an issue of permissions? or is this an issue of reading a json file from a location in inetpub requires a different method?

Any help is appreciated to better understand this.

Thank you,
Erasmo

Comment: Is this full exception?

Comment: What does the string returned by `System.IO.File.ReadAllText(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TokenFilePath"])` look like?  Is it an empty string?

Comment: @dbc, yes it is an empty string.

Comment: Well that's the problem.  An empty string isn't well-formed JSON, see [What is the minimum valid JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18419428).   Json.NET will throw an exception if you try to parse an empty string (or any other malformed JSON) into a `JObject`.