# How do I get this call to httpClient.GetFromJsonAsync() to work?

Tags: c#, json, http, blazor

I have two similar calls on a Blazor page:

```
private async void SelectQuiz()
    {
        List<String>? ls  = await httpClient.GetFromJsonAsync<List<String>>("api/BgQuizAnswer/GetBgQuizList");
        String?       txt = await httpClient.GetFromJsonAsync<String>      ("api/BgQuizAnswer/GetHello");
```

The first call works fine while the second one fails.

```
        [HttpGet]
        [Route("GetBgQuizList")]
        public ActionResult<List<String>> GetBgQuizList()
        {
            return _bgQuizAnswerService.GetBgQuizList();
        }
        [HttpGet]
        [Route("GetHello")]
        public ActionResult<String> GetHello()
        {
            return "Hello";
        }
```

Here's the start of the error messages I get when I inspect the page:
Unhandled Exception:
System.Text.Json.JsonException: 'H' is an invalid start of a value. Path: $ | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 0.
---> System.Text.Json.JsonReaderException: 'H' is an invalid start of a value. LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 0.
Note that the 'H' is the first letter of the return string. If I change 'Hello' to 'Jello', the error complains about 'J'.

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to retrieve content as JSON, but your API doesn't return it as JSON. Thus you need to change your `GetHello` method to correct this:

```
        [HttpGet]
        [Route("GetHello")]
        public ActionResult<String> GetHello()
        {
            return Json("Hello");
        }
```

Why is this not necessary for `GetBgQuizList`? Because ASP.NET Core serialises complex types like lists to JSON as default.

Comment: This gives the follow compile error: CS0103 The name 'Json' does not exist in the current context

Comment: I'm not sure what to tell you, it's a built-in method on all controllers: https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controller.json

Comment: Error CS0103 The name 'Json' does not exist in the current context

Answer (score 1):

A valid JSON should be enclosed with `{...}` (braces) which represents an object or `[...]` (square brackets) which represents an array.

The API for the second HttpClient call returns a string.

You should use [`GetStringAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient.getstringasync?view=net-7.0) to get the string value.

```cs
String? txt = await httpClient.GetStringAsync("api/BgQuizAnswer/GetHello");
```

Comment: *A valid JSON should be enclosed with `{...}` (braces) which represents an object or `[...]` (square brackets) which represents an array.* - this was true with RFC-4627 but is no longer true with RFC-8259, which allows the root JSON value to be a primitive.  See [What is the minimum valid JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22361229).

Comment: @dbc - yes,  it is allowed to be `"Hello"` but it now is just `Hello`.

Comment: @HH - right, that's the problem exactly.

Comment: This doesn't work:             return "{Hello}";

Comment: String? txt = await httpClient.GetStringAsync<String>("api/BgQuizAnswer/GetHello"); gives this compile error: CS0308 The non-generic method 'HttpClient.GetStringAsync(string?)' cannot be used with type arguments

Comment: Should be `await httpClient.GetStringAsync("api/BgQuizAnswer/GetHello")`. This method does not support generic.

Answer (score 0):

Replacing 
return "Hello";
with
return JsonSerializer.Serialize("Hello");
works.
Replacing
String?       txt = await httpClient.GetFromJsonAsync      ("api/BgQuizAnswer/GetHello");
with 
String? txt = await httpClient.GetStringAsync("api/BgQuizAnswer/GetHello");
also works.