# How does one convert a JSON string value to a VARCHAR value (excluding quotes) in H2?

Tags: sql, json, h2

I have a H2 database (version **2.2.220**) with data in a `JSON` column; I need to migrate the column via a SQL script so that the data is in a conventional relational database structure. The main stumbling block is that on extraction of a JSONValue string value (surrounded by double quotes in JSON format), I am struggling to convert this into a `VARCHAR` value that does not include the surrounding double quotes.

I hope the below SQL statements illustrate the issue in the most rudimentary way:

1. ```sql
   create table my_table (
       id        int generated by default as identity,
       my_json   JSON null default null,
   );

   insert into my_table (my_json) values (JSON '"abcdef"');
   ```

   The double quotes inside the string constant is necessary, else it is not recognized as valid JSON.
2. **1st** query (naive):

   ```sql
   select my_json from my_table;
   ```

   This returns `"abcdef"` with quotes included in the string. I would however like the raw string value `abcdef` to be returned without the surrounding quotes.
3. **2nd** query (typecasting):

   ```sql
   select CAST(my_json as VARCHAR(255)) from my_table;
   ```

   This still returns `"abcdef"` with quotes included in the string.
4. **3rd** query ("brute-force" trimming):

   ```sql
   select BTRIM(my_json, '"') from my_table;
   ```

   This achieves the desired result `abcdef`, but is problematic. One way this will cause  a bug is when the string value should intentionally include a double quote at the beginning and/or end, e.g. `xyz"` (`JSON '"xyz\""'`) - this will be trimmed to return `xyz\`.

**I am wondering if there is a "recommended"/cleaner way to do this conversion that is less bug-prone.**

## Related/Interesting

- [Wikipedia: JSON data types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#Data_types)
- [Stackoverflow: What is the minimum valid JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18419428/what-is-the-minimum-valid-json)
- [JSON formatter & validator](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/)

Comment: Is `"abcdef"` a valid JSON document? How so?

Comment: @TheImpaler it depends on which specification is followed, but H2 certainly accepts `JSON '"abcdef"'` (in the `insert` statement) without giving an error (it does show an error for obviously invalid JSON). Also refer to [What is the minimum valid JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18419428/what-is-the-minimum-valid-json), which mentions at least 3 JSON standards (cue the [xkcd cartoon](https://xkcd.com/927/)) that accepts JSONValues, including string values, as valid.

Comment: As the adage says: "The good thing about standards is there are so many of them."